# c# twilio client browser to browser calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

i am in the process of writing a c# mvc.net application and need to know if i can end twilio client calls after a certain amount of time and also play recording during the call when the call has reached a certain time limit or a recording the says "This call will end in 30 seconds". any help is good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do a little work to make this work as `duration` is an empty value until after the call terminates. Instead, use the [`StartTime` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance) on a call and calculate the duration manually in your application.

After implementing that you can [modify the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) using the [`<Play>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) to play a recording during the call with your warning message and [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup) the call once it reached the specified time.

An example modification in [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install) would look like:

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "ACCOUNT_SID";
    string AuthToken = "AUTH_TOKEN";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    twilio.RedirectCall("CALL_SID", 
        "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", "POST");
  }
```